# How to display XML correctly when converting RSS to Plain XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, rss

So basically, I have this RSS feed in hand. I converted the RSS into XmlDocument by the following:

```
 Public Function GroveHallFromRss() As String
        Dim webClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim ourUrl As String = "http://abc.123.org/RSSSyndicator.aspx?type=N&range=currentyear&expire=Y&location=2-7-165&rssid=18"
        Dim stream AS Stream
    stream = webClient.OpenRead(ourUrl)
    Dim xmlDocument AS XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
        xmlDocument.Load(stream)

        Dim root As XmlNode = xmlDocument.DocumentElement
    Return root.OuterXml.ToString

    End Function
```

With above, I'm able to get the content of the RSS, but it begin with the `<string>` tag and end with the `</string>` tag. The contents in between are all plain texts squeezed together.

If I remove the OuterXml part, and just `Return root.ToString`, I got the following:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.
>          `<string>System.Xml.XmlElement</string>`

So I'm wondering how could I display the converted RSS as any other XML file with the nodes styled. (but not rendered and displayed by browser as RSS, but only styled XML)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need, in your current code to load the XML into the XmlDocument object.  For instance, the following does the same thing:

```
Public Function GroveHallFromRss() As String
    Dim webClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
    Dim ourUrl As String = "http://abc.123.org/RSSSyndicator.aspx?type=N&range=currentyear&expire=Y&location=2-7-165&rssid=18"
    Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(webClient.OpenRead(ourUrl))
    Return streamReader.ReadToEnd()
End Function
```

However, that doesn't answer your question about properly indenting the document.  To do that, the easiest way, I believe, it to apply a stylesheet. The following XSLT script will make an XML document pretty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can apply the XSLT script in your code thusly:

```
Public Function GroveHallFromRss() As String
    Dim webClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
    Dim ourUrl As String = "http://abc.123.org/RSSSyndicator.aspx?type=N&range=currentyear&expire=Y&location=2-7-165&rssid=18"
    Dim reader as XmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(webClient.OpenRead(ourUrl))
    Dim transformer As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform()
    transformer.Load("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform""><xsl:output method=""xml"" indent=""yes""/><xsl:strip-space elements=""*""/><xsl:template match=""/""><xsl:copy-of select="".""/></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>")
    Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = transformer.OutputSettings
    Dim outputStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim xmlWriter As XmlWriter = xmlWriter.Create(outputStream, settings)
    transformer.Transform(reader, Nothing, xmlWriter)
    outputStream.Position = 0
    Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(outputStream)
    Return = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, actually my friend helped me with a small change. That is changing As String to As XmlDocument. that did it. so "Public Function GroveHallFromRss() As XmlDocument" Thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, actually my friend helped me with a small change. That is changing As String to As XmlDocument. that did it. so "Public Function GroveHallFromRss() As XmlDocument" Thanks for you help though.